# Errors encountered executing: tessera tmstyle:///

Tags: mapbox, node-js

I am trying to follow demo provided [here](https://www.azavea.com/blog/2015/05/29/converting-mapbox-studio-vector-tiles-to-rasters-2/). Tessera (a Tilelive implementation) is supposed to serve .tm2 files created in Mapbox Studio Classic to localhost using node js.  The errors returned seem vague to me. I am posting here reaching out hoping someone else has experienced this and can provide some insight.  Here is what I have tried.

Install the dependencies...

```
 npm install -g tessera tl mbtiles mapnik tilelive tilelive-file tilelive-http tilelive-mapbox tilelive-mapnik tilelive-s3 tilelive-tmsource tilelive-tmstyle tilelive-utfgrid tilelive-vector tilejson
```

Set global environmental variable MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN (windows, although I can use cygwin to echo and return correctly the correct mapbox token)

```
export MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN=pk.eyJ1Ijoid3RnZW9ncmFwaGVyIiwiYSI6IlR2a2VuQWsifQ.U3TabizicU3kZ4LvkHyb0g
```

And finally execute the Tessera cmd...

```
tessera tmstyle:///path/to/terrain.tm2
```

Then it acts as if if is starting server on port 8080 but throws the following error...

```
$ tessera tmstyle:///path/to/terrain.tm2
Listening at http://0.0.0.0:8080/
C:\Users\wtgeo_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tessera\server.js:47
        throw err;
        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'class' of undefined
    at Renderer.render (C:\Users\wtgeo_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tilelive-tmstyle\node_modules\carto\lib\carto\renderer.js:117:25)
    at C:\Users\wtgeo_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tilelive-tmstyle\index.js:210:52
    at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\wtgeo_000\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tessera\node_modules\tilelive-cache\node_modules\locking-cache\index.js:74:25)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Following the returned msg I open the tessera server.js file and it is simply the throw error msg providing (to me atleast) little insight.

Comment: It appears that carto module is expecting a stylesheet with a class property. https://github.com/mapbox/carto/blob/master/lib/carto/renderer.js#L125 but tmstyle doesn't provide that property. https://github.com/mojodna/tilelive-tmstyle/blob/master/index.js#L125 Too bad they don't provide you with a package.json, seems like it could be a versioning issue.

Comment: Hey thank you for this insight.  I believe you are hitting close with the versioning issue. What I have found now is that when I export from mapbox studio classic to .tm2 the export completes without error but items are not present.  Alternatively I can use any of the tm2 files available on mapbox github page [example here](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-outdoors.tm2) and do not receive the error?